# Which message is used on authenticated ip packets using HMAC-MD5?

Tags: cryptography, udp, md5, cisco

This is not a programming question per se, but it is related to a c program that I am trying to make in order to respond the ip sla control messages sent by a cisco router.  I know that it uses MD5 using and a key chain in order to authenticate the packet (Could be MD5 or HMAC). I know about the theory about HMAC and MD5 and all about the message and the key and all that stuff that the theory on the book give us... but I have a question that does not seems very simple at least to me that is at the end Which is the "message" that is hashed and added to the packet so the other end could know that he packet is valid?

Thanks for your help...

EDIT:
I have two routers one acting as a ip sla generator and another one as an ip sla responder. The ip sla generator authenticate the data sent by using MD5 and a key.

Capturing the packets that left the ip sla generator interface with Wireshark I found this:

Packet not Authenticated:
IP header
4500005000000000ff1136e3c0a801c3c0a801a6
UDP Header
e2e607af003ccdbd
Payload
01040034000000000004001000000000c0a801a6ea6014500001001c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Packet Authenticated with key "cisco":
IP Header
4500005000000000ff1136e3c0a801c3c0a801a6
UDP Header
c20107af003cd296
Payload
01040034000000000004001000000000c0a801a6ea6014500001001c00000000**01ff0000b9c0ae94fec238bd43d13129a6625eda**

*where at the end of the payload you could see 0x01ff that is the key number used to authenticate the packet and 0xb9c0ae94fec238bd43d13129a6625ed that is the authentication string

Capturing another Authenticated packet with key "cisco" I got this:
IP Header
4500005000000000ff1136e3c0a801c3c0a801a6
UDP Header
d47607af003cc021
Payload
01040034000000000004001000000000c0a801a6ea6014500001001c00000000**01ff0000b9c0ae94fec238bd43d13129a6625eda**

As you could see the UDP header changes but the authenticated message remains the same, that lead me to infer that the message to hash is just the payload but hashing the following combinations does not produce the authentication needed:

- MD5 of the payload not authenticated
- MD5 of the payload not authenticated + key in Hex
- Hmac-Md5 of the payload not authenticated
- Hmac-Md5 of the payload not authenticated + key in Hex
- A lot more combinations too long to be listed...

So i think that the message is not as simple as the payload or the Authentication Method used by Cisco is not standard. Am I missing something? or There is something else I could try?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: yes, it depends on the protocol (which I cannot find). I don't see any mention of HMAC in the documentation though, so it is much more likely that the key is included as last part in the hash calculation, but is not in the package (of course). This is different from appending zero's. The plain MD5 hash is then used as some poor man's authentication scheme.

All this from the confusing docs from Cisco and the relatively hard to read question - and general knowledge of crypto, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry if the question is hard to read, I will try to explain it better, editing the question...

Comment: Try to concatenate the **binary** plain text of the payload with the **binary** payload of the key (both post-fix and then pre-fix if it does not work). Normally you don't sign the **encoding** of the data, just the data itself. Cryptographic API's usually work at byte level.

Comment: Sadly no luck. I tried with the binary payload and key but I am still not getting the same result maybe I am just doing something wrong... When you said abut trying postfix or prefix the key what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Normally you would put the key data after the normal data I suppose, but it might be that they preprend the key before hashing. I think you are being bitten by the fact that we don't have any standard to go on. If you can point me towards a standard, it should be easy, before that it's guessing.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem too, unfortunately ipsla is a Cisco proprietary protocol and i could not find any information regarding the conformation of the UDP packets and the authentication, I am beginning to think that the authentication is not standard and is Cisco proprietary but based on MD5.